# Redux and react-router, not updating

Tags: reactjs

I use `Redux` and `react-router` together, but, when I click, `*location*` and `*match*` doesn't want to update, but the router is working, because I can see what I want in my URL.

I have to reload to see changes.

I don't know where I make a mistake.
My connect is good, i tried to add `*{pure: false}*`, but nothing happened.

If you have an idea :)

```
import * as React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import {connect} from "react-redux"


class Menu extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    render() {
        const {categories, match, location, history} = this.props;
        return (
            <Router>
                <div className="wrapper portfolio">
                    <nav className="tri">
                        <ul>
                            <FilterLink props={this.props} match={match} location={location} history={history}/>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    {
                        categories.alldata.data[0].map((categorie, index) => {
                            return (
                                <Route path={'/' + categorie.slug} key={index}/>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

const FilterLink = function ({props, match, location, history}) {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <li className={location.pathname === '/' ? 'active' : ''}>
                <Link to='/' slug='all'>
                    All
                </Link>
            </li>
            {console.log(match)}
            {console.log(location)}
            {props.categories.alldata.data[0].map((categorie, index) => {
                return (
                    <li key={index} className={location.pathname === '/' + categorie.slug ? 'active' : ''}>
                        <Link to={'/' + categorie.slug} slug={categorie.slug} key={index} name={categorie.name}>
                            {categorie.name}
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                )
            })}
        </React.Fragment>
    )
};


const mapStateToProps = function (state) {
    return {
        categories: state.alldata[1],
        categoryFilter: state.categoryFilter,
        rooterActualLink: state.rooterActualLink
    }
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Menu));
```

And console screenshot :
[Console Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRx7K.png)

Thx :)

Comment: redux connect 'has logic': state not changed - no reason to rerender

Comment: So, i need to dispatch the current location in the store ?

Comment: Try putting withRouter in main component like if you are building your app using create-react-app then that would be App.js file.

Comment: You mean add it to the connect ? I tried, nothing change.

I update the state too, so React re-render, but I can't get the current location (location, match and history always show me '/'), so nothing change

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this.

That was only because I had a  inside a general  container.

Don't do the same mistake ^^